# Auth not working in view

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to make certain buttons appear only to certain user types, I was adding this code around buttons in my view:

```
<li><?php
        if($this->Auth->user('role_id')==8){
                echo $this->Html->link(__('New Consumer Product'), array('action' => 'add'));
        }
    ?>
</li>
```

But that just gave me the error `Error: AuthHelper could not be found.` so I added the following in my AppController:

```
public $helpers = array('Auth');
```

However this just gave me the following error:

```
Helper class AuthHelper could not be found.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

What's happening here? Shouldn't it have worked when I added the Auth helper into my AppController?

I'd previously been using Auth in my UsersController with no problems at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Auth in the view. That's only for controllers.

There are actually a few options such as setting/passing a variable for it, but this is the correct way as per [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)

```
    if((AuthComponent::user('role_id') == 8) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your AppControllers `beforeRender()` or `beforeFilter()` just set the active user to the view:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    $this->set('userData', $this->Auth->user());
}
```

And work with that variable in the view. I prefer to not use the static method calls on the component inside a view, it's the wrong place for a component and also static calls aren't something you want to introduce a lot because of tight coupling.

My [BzUtils plugin](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-bz-utils) comes with a helper that can deal with this variable or can be configured to read the user data from session and offers some convenience methods.

Answer (score 1):

in cake 3.x I found the only thing that worked is to set the variable in AppController.php as so:

```
public function beforeRender(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
     $this->set(['userData'=> $this->Auth->user(),
     ]);
}
```

the key difference being you have to pass in $event...

Answer (score -3):

Auth is a component not a helper. There is no Auth helper.

You can read the Authenticated user from the following command

```
$user = $this->Session->read("Auth.User");
```